# autocomplete filter by category id - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i try to make autocomplete filter by category, like this
[image: search]

autocomplete has been success showing result when i entire id by manual, but when i try to get id by category id, id can't get id

this is my code javascript

$(function() {

```
  $(".keyword").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({
          url: "search/autocomplete",
          type: "GET",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {'id':$("#cate").change(function () {
            var end = this.value;
        })
        },
          success: function(data) {
              response($.map(data, function(item) {
                return {
                  label: item.value,
                  value: item.value
              };
              }));
          }
      });
    },
    select:function(event,ui) {
      $(".keyword").val(ui.item.label);
      return false;
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      window.location = "/lessons/" + ui.item.value;
  }
  }).bind('focus', function () {
    $('.ui-autocomplete').css('z-index','9999').css('overflow-y','scroll').css('max-height','300px');
    // $('.ui-autocomplete').css('background','#09121a').css('color','#fff');
    // $('.ui-menu .ui-menu-item-wrapper').css('padding','11px 1em 3px 1.4em !important');
    // $(this).autocomplete("search");
    // var btncategory = $('.btn-category').width();
    // var left = '-'+btncategory+'px';
  });
});
```

this is my html

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" id="cate">
             <a class="dropdown-item" value="'.$category->id.'" href="javascript:void(0)"  onclick="changeCategory(&apos;'.$category->title.'&apos;)">'. $category->title.'</a>
              <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="changeCategory('Semua Kategori')">Semua Kategori</a>
            </div>
          </div>
```

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set the id to the result of adding a change handler which isn't going to work. The data for the $.ajax call can only be an object, string, or array. What you should do is setup the event handler separately to handle the change, store the data, and trigger the autocomplete manually. Give this a try:

```
let autocompleteData = {};

$("#cate").change(function () {
    autocompleteData.id = this.value;
    $(".keyword").autocomplete("search");
};

$(".keyword").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "search/autocomplete",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: autocompleteData
    },
```

The idea is to have your data be an object that always exists. It is initially set to an empty object so it will have no result. Whenever your category id changes, it sets the id property of that object to its value and triggers an autocomplete event. Whenever the autocomplete code is run it just uses whatever the current state of the autocompleteData object is, so it should always be passing the category id as part of the call.

Comment: thank you for your response, but when i try to your code, response data is null, how to solve?

Comment: Try the same code with a hardcoded id value, like `data: { 'id': 'Cisco' }`. If that works then you can rule out the problem of the Ajax code and the backend to focus on just the event handling code.

Comment: Also, I just now realized that you have a "dropdown" that is not an actual form control and is instead something made to behave like one. Without seeing more code, I highly doubt the "change" event handling works in this case. What does your `changeCategory` method do? Can you post that code?